# Calculating distance to a row with a certain value

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a data with pandas in which a maintenance work is done at a location. The maintenance is done every four years at each site. I want to find the years since the last maintenance action at each site. I am giving here only two sites in the following example but in the original dataset, I have thousands of them. My data only covers the years 2014 through 2017.

Action = 0 means no action has been performed that year, Action = 1 means some action has been done. Measurement is a performance reading related to the effect of the action. The action can happen in any year. I know that if the action has been performed in Year Y, the previous maintenance has been performed in Year Y-4.

```
 Site  Year   Action  Measurement
   A   2014     0         100
   A   2015     0         150
   A   2016     1         300
   A   2017     0         80
   B   2014     0         200
   B   2015     1         250
   B   2016     0         60
   B   2017     0         110
```

Given this dataset; first, I want to have a temporary dataset like this:

```
 Item  Year   Action  Measurement  Years_Since_Last_Action
   A   2014     0         100           2
   A   2015     0         150           3
   A   2016     1         300           4
   A   2017     0         80            1
   B   2014     0         200           3
   B   2015     1         250           4
   B   2016     0         60            1
   B   2017     0         110           2
```

Then, I want to have:

```
Years_Since_Last_Action         Mean_Measurement
        1                            70
        2                            105
        3                            175
        4                            275
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the actions occur regularly in that pattern (i.e. 1, 0, 0, 1, ...) for each site, or is it possible for actions to take place at a site even during intermediary years?

Comment: There is no pattern of occurring. For a given site it can happen in any year. But, it will happen only once during that four year period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first question

```
s=df.loc[df.Action==1,['Site','Year']].set_index('Site') # get all year have the action and map back to the whole dataframe
df['Newyear']=df.Site.map(s.Year)
s1=df.Year-df.Newyear
df['action since last year']=np.where(s1<=0,s1+4,s1)# using np.where get the condition
df
Out[167]: 
  Site  Year  Action  Measurement  Newyear  action since last year
0    A  2014       0          100     2016                       2
1    A  2015       0          150     2016                       3
2    A  2016       1          300     2016                       4
3    A  2017       0           80     2016                       1
4    B  2014       0          200     2015                       3
5    B  2015       1          250     2015                       4
6    B  2016       0           60     2015                       1
7    B  2017       0          110     2015                       2
```

2nd question

```
df.groupby('action since last year').Measurement.mean()
Out[168]: 
action since last year
1     70
2    105
3    175
4    275
Name: Measurement, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What if you had multiple years where actions were taken for each site though? How would `map` work there?

Comment: I found an alt ;-)

Answer (score 3):

First, build your intermediate using `groupby`, `*fill` and a little arithmetic.

```
v = (df.Year
       .where(df.Action.astype(bool))
       .groupby(df.Site)
       .ffill()
       .bfill()
       .sub(df.Year))
df['Years_Since_Last_Action'] = np.select([v > 0, v < 0], [4 - v, v.abs()], default=4)
```

```
df
  Site  Year  Action  Measurement  Years_Since_Last_Action
0    A  2014       0          100                      2.0
1    A  2015       0          150                      3.0
2    A  2016       1          300                      4.0
3    A  2017       0           80                      1.0
4    B  2014       0          200                      3.0
5    B  2015       1          250                      4.0
6    B  2016       0           60                      1.0
7    B  2017       0          110                      2.0
```

Next,

```
df.groupby('Years_Since_Last_Action', as_index=False).Measurement.mean()

   Years_Since_Last_Action  Measurement
0                      1.0           70
1                      2.0          105
2                      3.0          175
3                      4.0          275
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
delta_year = df.loc[df.groupby("Site")["Action"].transform("idxmax"), "Year"].values
years_since = ((df.Year - delta_year) % 4).replace(0, 4)
df["Years_Since_Last_Action"] = years_since

out = df.groupby("Years_Since_Last_Action")["Measurement"].mean().reset_index()
out = out.rename(columns={"Measurement": "Mean_Measurement"})
```

which gives me

```
In [230]: df
Out[230]: 
  Site  Year  Action  Measurement  Years_Since_Last_Action
0    A  2014       0          100                        2
1    A  2015       0          150                        3
2    A  2016       1          300                        4
3    A  2017       0           80                        1
4    B  2014       0          200                        3
5    B  2015       1          250                        4
6    B  2016       0           60                        1
7    B  2017       0          110                        2

In [231]: out
Out[231]: 
   Years_Since_Last_Action  Mean_Measurement
0                        1                70
1                        2               105
2                        3               175
3                        4               275
```

Comment: This solution is also a very elegant one, thank you!